# to calculate remaining loan balance

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program in C to calculate the remaining balance after 1st, 2nd & 3rd monthly payments, given the loan, monthly payment amount, and interest rate. I am having a problem in entering the input (floating point numbers) i.e it only takes one input (loan) & displays the answer without considering the other 2 inputs (interest rate & monthly payments).

This problem occurs only when I use the floating-point numbers (even in other programs also). I want to ask if this is due to coding or due to any other reason.

My code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>    
main()    
{    
   float loan,interest,monthly_payment;      
   float balance_Imonth,balance_IImonth,balance_IIImonth;    

   printf("Enter the amount of loan: ");  
   scanf("%.2f",&loan);  

   printf("Enter the amount of interest: ");  
   scanf("%.2f",&interest);  

   printf("Enter the amount of monthly payment: ");  
   scanf("%.2f",&monthly_payment);   

   balance_Imonth=((interest/(100*12))*loan)+(loan)-(monthly_payment);  
   balance_IImonth=((interest/(100*12))*loan)+(balance_Imonth)-  (monthly_payment);  
   balance_IIImonth=((interest/(100*12))*loan)+(balance_IImonth)-(monthly_payment);  

   printf("Balance remaining after I payment:   $%.2f\n",balance_Imonth);  
   printf("Balance remaining after II payment:  $%.2f\n",balance_IImonth);  
   printf("Balance remaining after III payment: $%.2f\n",balance_IIImonth);  
}
```

Comment: On a somewhat related note, [it isn't the best idea to use floating point math when dealing with money](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/274261).

Comment: It is asked in the question to find the balance in decimals @ArjunShankar. I am not having very good programming skills, I am a beginner. This is the reason I am facing this difficulty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format specification `"%.2f"` is OK for `printf` but not for `scanf`. Use just `"%f"`.

In your program, all the `scanf` function calls fail. You are just seeing undefined behavior due to use of uninitialized variables.

Always check the return value of `scanf` to make sure that the operation succeeded before you proceed to use the variables in which `scanf` stores the results.

Use

```
if ( scanf("%f", &loan) != 1 )
{
  // Deal with error.
}
```